# How to read Keras checkpoint in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I used `ch_callback = ModelCheckpoint('./foo.bar')` with my `model.fit()`. And I got exactly what I requested, namely a `'./foo.bar'` file.

- What format does it actually have?
- How can this checkpoint be used, where can I load it?
- Most importantly, can I convert it to native tensorflow checkpoint format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Keras checkpoint is in .hdf5 or .h5 format.
2. You can load the keras checkpoint using `tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")`.
3. If you want to convert Keras checkpoint to TF checkpoint, you can load your Keras model (with the Keras backend), then export a TF checkpoint of the TF graph created when loading the Keras model.

```
model = keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
sess = keras.backend.get_session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

Answer (score 0):

for `tensorflow 2.x`

this code worked for me

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model

saver = tf.train.Checkpoint()
model = load_model('model.hdf5', compile=False)
sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()

save_path = saver.save("model.ckpt")
```